# Putty / Kitty send some type of hidden characters?

Tags: putty, kitty

When I try to edit a file via `vi`, PuTTY` / KiTTY sends some type of characters every 3 seconds.

Here's what I see:

```
P 
P
```

if I view a `man` page, the bell goes off every 3 seconds.

Due to this behavior I'm no longer able to edit anything.

Any ideas?

I tried searching google, and the PuTTY & KiTTY FAQs, but couldn't find anything (to be fair, I don't know what to search for though).

Comment: What settings do you have around keepalive?

Comment: Current setting is "0" (Off)

Comment: Wondering if there is a better forum to post this question?  I can't believe I'm the only one experiencing this issue (and on two different systems now).